Is it possible to solve $3f(x)^2 - 2f(x)^3 - c = 0$?
I am trying to solve for $x$, from
$$3f(x)^2 - 2f(x)^3 - c = 0$$
where $f(x) = 1-(1-x)^b$, $c \in (0,1)$ and $b>0$. I don't remember very well how to resolve this type of thing, is it legal to resolve $3u^2 - 2u^3 - c = 0$? and then solve for $x$? The only thing I know is that there is a root in the interval $(0,1)$, and I am interested in finding this root. Is it possible to solve for $x$ without resorting to numerical methods? I appreciate any reference or suggestion. Greetings

Apparently it is solvable in closed form

Not sure what it means to "solve" this, as $b,c$ are unknown.  Do you intend to write down a solution as a function of $b,c$?

Yes equations of these kinds are solvable using a modified Cardano's formula. Cite Casus irreducibilis for more information about solving cubic polynomials with distinct real roots. Consider a depressed cubic of the form $x^3+px+q=0$, with only one real root. According to Cardano's works the real root is given by,
$$x = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac q2 +\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4 + \frac {p^3}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{-\dfrac q2 -\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4 + \frac {p^3}{27}}}$$
When $\frac {q^2}4 + \frac {p^3}{27} < 0$, the original depressed cubic will have 3 distinct roots instead (as in your case). They can be obtained by using the cube roots of unity: $1, \omega, \omega^2$ $$k=1,2,3$$
$$x_k=\omega_k\sqrt[3]{-\dfrac q2 +\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4 + \frac {p^3}{27}}}+\omega^2_k\sqrt[3]{-\dfrac q2 -\sqrt{\frac {q^2}4 + \frac {p^3}{27}}}$$
The roots are real because $\omega^2$ is the complex conjugate of $\omega$ and similar observation is true for the expressions inside square roots.$$3f(x)^2-2f(x)^3 -c = 0$$
Let, $$t=\frac{1}{f(x)}, f(x) \in (0,1) \implies t \in (1,\infty)$$
$$\frac{3}{t^2}-\frac{2}{t^3}-c=0 \implies t^3-\frac{3}{c}t+\frac{2}{c}=0$$
Where $p=-\dfrac{3}{c}, q=\dfrac{2}{c} \implies \dfrac{1}{c^2}-\dfrac{1}{c^3}<0$ and thus can be solved by the above-mentioned.
